# Password and conform password should be the same

Tags: android, validation, passwords

I have two edit text fields like password and confirm-password if both the entries are true then password  string value should be passed to server, but i m not getting the correct response from the server in log-cat, I am getting negative response

what is the wrong with this code? help me to solve this.

```
 EditText  etxt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regetpwd);
          EditText  etxt_confirmpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regetrepwd)
              password =  etxt_password.getText().toString(); 
          confirmpassword =  etxt_confirmpassword.getText().toString();

        if (confirmpassword != null && password != null) 
   {
   if (password.equals(confirmpassword)) 
   {
        request.addProperty("password", password);

   } 
 }
```

where request is the SOAP object through which I m passing the value to server

Comment: Is my understanding correct that this code is working correctly, but it is the server call that is failing? If that's the case, then what is the relevance of this code to the actual problem?

Comment: You want us to debug your server by looking at a couple EditTexts and a String comparison?  You're going to have to provide a bit more than that if you want help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks fine to me, but I've been awake for 40 hours straight... so thats not really much to go on.  the only thing I can suggest is trying to combine the two if statements (you only need to know one is not null and that the two are equal to get a valid password).  the other thing to try would be to maybe check the length > 0 rather than check null?  I can't recall if an empty EditText returns null or empty string when you do a `getText().toString()` on it...

```
if ((confirmpassword != null) && password.equals(confirmpassword)) {
      request.addProperty("password", password);
}
```